# how to fix two arrows turn same time when I only touch one sidebar

Tags: html, css

I want to create a website but when I create the sidebar, then I want to add a submenu to the sidebar, but when I touch one sidebar the two arrows turn together. I try to adjust them but I don't know to want to add what anymore. Then where can I add submenu script in HTML.

[image]

-- two arrows turn together when touching one

```css
.main_box .sidebar_menu {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 280px;
  left: -280px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

.sidebar_menu .menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
  width: 100%;
}

.sidebar_menu .menu li {
  margin-top: 6px;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.sidebar_menu .menu i {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-right: 8px;
}

.sidebar_menu .menu li span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 20px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  transition: transform 0.4s;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #fff;
}

.sidebar_menu .menu:hover li span {
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-180deg);
}

.sidebar_menu .menu a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar_menu .menu li:hover {
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <i class="fas fa-qrcode"> Friends<span class="fas fa-caret-down"></span></i>
    </li>
    <li>
      <i class="fas fa-stream"> Updates<span class="fas fa-caret-down"></span></i>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your css rule

```
.sidebar_menu .menu:hover li span {
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-180deg);
}
```

to

```
.sidebar_menu .menu li:hover span {
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-180deg);
}
```

Your version tells **all** LI inside a hovered over DOM element with class *menu* to transform the SPAN(s) inside them; my version targets the hovered over LI.